# Why are filenames renamed in typo3 creating a new relation

Tags: typo3, lowercase

When I try to create a new relation in a content-element of TYPO3 (8.7.15) it renames the filename from uppercase to lowercase letters (File123.png -> file123.png)
Also I can't create a folder with uppercase letters?

Does anyone have an idea? I've looked into the installation tool but  I can't  find anything.

cu
Volker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*checking the "Uses case sensitive identifiers" box?*

-->https://forge.typo3.org/issues/55652

Comment: that's it 
I just wanted to add the solution ;)